# removing duplicated names for array in c

Tags: arrays, c, struct, c-strings, function-definition

this is what i have to make: c. It should be possible to remove an animal with a specified name. If more animals with the same name exist, it should remove all the animal with the same name.

this is my code:

```
void deleteAnimalByName(char *animalName, int *nrOfAnimals, ANIMAL *animalArray)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < *nrOfAnimals; i ++)
   {
       if(strcmp((animalArray + i)->Name, animalName) == 0)
       {
           for(int j = i; j < *nrOfAnimals - 1; j++)
           {
            animalArray[j] = animalArray[j + 1];
           }
           (*nrOfAnimals)--;
       }
   }
}
```

the outcome after tyring to delete the animals with the same name:
Animals in shelter: 1

Name: ted

Species: Parrot

Age: 1

only one gets deleted, the other one stays. what could cause this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must provide a complete minimal code. So that others can see the full context and also to be able to run it for direct debugging. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

For starters the function should be declared at least like

```
size_t deleteAnimalByName( ANIMAL *animalArray, size_t nrOfAnimals, const char *animalName );
```

And the function can be defined like

```
size_t deleteAnimalByName( ANIMAL *animalArray, size_t nrOfAnimals, const char *animalName )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < nrOfAnimals; i++ )
    {
        if ( strcmp( animalArray[i].Name, animalName ) != 0 )
        {
            if ( n != i ) animalArray[n] = animalArray[i];
            ++n;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

As for your approach then it at least is inefficient because you move all elements of the array one position left after finding an element that need to be deleted.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ANIMAL
{
    char *Name;
} ANIMAL;

size_t deleteAnimalByName( ANIMAL *animalArray, size_t nrOfAnimals, const char *animalName )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < nrOfAnimals; i++ )
    {
        if ( strcmp( animalArray[i].Name, animalName ) != 0 )
        {
            if ( n != i ) animalArray[n] = animalArray[i];
            ++n;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    ANIMAL animalArray[] =
    {
        { "hare" }, { "hare" }, { "fox" }, { "hare" }
    };
    
    size_t nrOfAnimals = sizeof( animalArray ) / sizeof( *animalArray );
    
    nrOfAnimals = deleteAnimalByName( animalArray, nrOfAnimals, "hare" );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < nrOfAnimals; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s ", animalArray[i].Name );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
fox
```

Comment: @DaboLongwoods I do not know what code you run. See the demonstrative program. in my question. Look how the function is called. It seems you are calling the function incorrectly.

Comment: and what if the user adds an animal with scanf?

Comment: @DaboLongwoods What do you mean?

Comment: @DaboLongwoods The demonstrative program is simplified to show only how the function can be defined.

Comment: for this program i let the user add an animal name, let it choose a species and an age with this code:

int addAnimal(const ANIMAL *AnimalPtr, ANIMAL *animalArray, int *nrOfAnimals)
{
    if(*nrOfAnimals < MaxNrAnimals)
    {
        animalArray[*nrOfAnimals] = *AnimalPtr; 
        *nrOfAnimals = *nrOfAnimals + 1;
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

Comment: @DaboLongwoods As I said I showed how the function can be defined. That is I answered your original question. If you have some other problems with your program then ask a new question closing this one.

Comment: i did exactly what you said. but this doesn't work: size_t nrOfAnimals = sizeof( animalArray ) / sizeof( *animalArray );

it says animalArray is undefined.

Comment: @DaboLongwoods As I said I do not know how your program looks. I showed how the function can be written. Do you have any question relative to the function definition? As for the previous your comment then it seems in main the array of structures is named something else apart from animalArray.